# How to install software in linux using windows?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, apt-get, ubuntu-12.10

I have windows 7 running, but I have the machine inside a domain, with Active Directory. I need to install likewise in a virtual machine running linux (Ubuntu), but unless I connect the VM to internet, I can't installed it using the apt-get command, so I need to download all the sources with Windows and then install them on the VM, in that way, I can log the VM into Active Directory and then, I'll have internet... how can I do this?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You want to download VirtualBox using Windows and install in Linux? If so, did you at least try downloading the .deb or .rpm packages from the site and attempt to install them? If any dependencies are missing I guess you would have received an error informing you of the same.

Comment: No. I have one installation of Ubuntu 12.10 inside Windows with VirtualBox. The Virtual Machine has access to the network, but the FW its blocking it from access to the internet, since it has to be inside our domain (with Active Directory). I can do this with "likewise", but I can't installed it with apt-get since the VM has not access to the internet, so I want to download it with Windows, and then copy that to the VM @Karan

Comment: So doesn't that program have a package or even sources that you can download (and make/compile if required)?

Comment: @Karan, I havn't found the sources. But the problem remains. If I like to compile, then I need all the libraries to compile it, and I'll be back again to the same problem but with other package. I've tried to share the connection of the windows machine with the VM, but I can't do it (I don't know why, when I do it backwards - from Ubuntu to the VM Windows - it works ok...)

Comment: Well, somewhere up the line you'll need a pre-compiled binary package for the program and required dependencies. If for example gcc is required to compile then there are packages available for it. However, have you first tried asking about your internet sharing problem? If that's solved, there'll be no need to even go down this route.

Comment: It's not at all clear why the VM can't access the Internet. Active Directory in and of itself does not restrict clients from accessing external networks. Is the network configured with network access control?  If so, you should work with your network administrator. If not, then your VM may not be configured correctly. Can you access internal network resources from the VM?

Comment: How is the networking setup in your VM?  If you use NAT networking mode your VM should be able to use the host computer's internet connection without any problems.

Comment: @BaconBits yes, it can access the network resources, and it has access control.

Comment: @heavyd If I configure it with NAT still doesn't have internet...

Comment: If your network administrator is using network access control, you're going to have to work with him to get your VM authenticated.  Anything else is probably going to get you in trouble with the powers that be and earn you a reprimand of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com). This makes all the packages in the Ubuntu package repository available for download.